# Requiring unknown module "NativeModules"

Tags: react-native

I have been trying to to generate a release version.
but I get this strange exception:

```
ReactNativeJS: Requiring unknown module "NativeModules"
```

and right after it I get :

```
Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

In my debug version everything works fine.

I have tried to checkout to the previous working commit.
and try to generate a version from it, but it fails with the same error.

maybe npm related issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with a library Called `rn-host-detect` that `reactotron-react-native` was using ...

I have sent a message to the author of the  and he fixed it.

removing  my `node_modules` and `npm install` again solved the issue.